# How to use the result of .then function to another function in js?

Tags: javascript, promise

Please help I want to use the result of function 1 (Fn1) in function 2 (Fn2).

```js
App={
st: null,//st is number value

Fn1: function() {
    App.contracts.contractName.deployed().then(function(instance){
       return instance.getST();
    }).then(function(result){      
        App.st = result;    
    });
},
Fn2: function() {
       alert(App.st)//
}    
}
```

Comment: Where and when are you calling `App.Fn2()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `Fn1` before `Fn2` to access it's value, so let's wrap `Fn1` into [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
App = {
    st: null,//st is number value

    Fn1: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            App.contracts.contractName.deployed().then(function(instance){
                return instance.getST();
            }).then(function(result){      
                App.st = result;
                resolve();
            }).catch(function(err){
                reject(err);
            })
        })
    },
    Fn2: function() {
        alert(App.st)
    }    
}
```

or better with [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await):

```js
App = {
    st: null,//st is number value

    Fn1: async function() {
        try {
            const instance = await App.contracts.contractName.deployed();
            const result = await instance.getST();
            App.st = result;
        } catch(err) {
            throw err;
        }
    },
    Fn2: function() {
        alert(App.st)
    }    
}
```

Now you can wait until `Fn1` exec before calling `Fn2`:

```js
App.Fn1().then(function() {
  App.Fn2()
})
```

or using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await):

```js
await App.Fn1()
App.Fn2()
```

Comment: **Warning**: This is the nested promise anti-pattern. `App.contracts.contractName.deployed()` **already returns a promise** - there is no point in creating another one.

Comment: @Quentin that's why I suggest OP to use _async/await_ where it's possible instead of old fashioned promise chaining/nesting

Comment: @Xeelley thanks, Both methods work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the `Promise` defined in `Fn1`

```js
Fn1: function() {
  return App.contracts.contractName.deployed().then((instance) => {
    return instance.getST();
  }).then((result) => {
    // Note that we return the assignment
    return App.st = result;
  });
}
```

Then you have two options, either you can call `Fn1` before `Fn2`

```js
App.Fn1().then(st => App.Fn2());
```

Or you can adjust `Fn2`'s implementation to call `Fn1` first.

```js
// simplistic solution
Fn2: function() {
  App.Fn1().then(st => {
    // do something with st
  });
}

// more robust solution
Fn2: function() {
  const resolveST = () => App.st != null ? Promise.resolve(App.st) : App.Fn1();
  resolveST().then(st => {
    // do something with st
  })
}
```

Then using `Fn2` is as simple as `App.Fn2()`